# array of objects,c++

Tags: c++, pointers, function, parameters

i have two classes namely `Flight` and `Runway`. Now i am trying to pass an array of these objects as parameter to a function.

```
void fun(Flight ptr1[],Runway ptr2[])
{
...
...
}
```

**ptr1 should point to an array of Flight objects and ptr2 should point to an array of Runway objects.**
Now inside this function fun() how do i access members of these classes. Also can i use ptr1++ or ptr2++ to move between the objects??
Also how would i be calling this func??something like this -

```
Flight array1[5];
Runway array2[2];
fun(array1,array2);
```

Comment: you can index a pointer just the way you index the array :) like ptr1[0], ptr1[1] etc

Comment: If you do this, don't use polymorphism on Flight or Runway. You'll shoot yourself in the foot before you can say aw.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using arrays rather than `std::vector`?

Comment: @outis: Because sometimes I don't need a dynamic array?

Comment: @ayush: What does your book have to say about it?

Comment: @GMan: That's not really a reason in my opinion... `std::vector` is way more powerful than a simple array (starting with iterators, which you'll use at some point even if you didn't plan on it originally...)

Comment: @rubenvb: Pointers can be iterators too, I don't follow the argument. How can you compare two things and say one is more powerful than the other when they're two different things? You wouldn't say airplanes are more powerful then cars, even after I specifically said I might not want to travel hundreds of miles. I might not want a dynamic array or dynamic allocation. You can't just say "use `vector`, not arrays" anymore than you can scoff and say "ha, why are you using a car when you could be piloting this plane?". They do different things.

Comment: @ruben: Pointers are first-class random access iterators, and any function requiring iterators, in `<algorithm>` or otherwise, accepts pointers.

Comment: @GMan, @Potatoswatter: I didn't know that pointers could be iterators. I take back my statement :)

Comment: @ruben: that's pretty much why iterators use pointer syntax. So that they can be compatible with pointers. :)

Comment: @GMan: I'm asking for ayush's specific reasons for this project, not reasons in general. Arrays shouldn't be used lightly. Neophytes should stick to std::vector unless they are studying arrays and pointers, else risk [bugs](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#arrays) and code complication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void fun(Flight ptr1[],Runway ptr2[])
```

is interpreted as

```
void fun(Flight *ptr1, Runway *ptr2)
```

This is called "decomposition," and I think it's rotten. It's mainly a feature for backward compatibility with C. If you want pointers, specify pointers, not arrays, because pointers and arrays are different things.

You can also do

```
void fun(Flight (&arr1)[5], Runway (&arr2)[7])
```

Now the parameters remain arrays inside the function, not pointers, so `++ arr1` is illegal and `sizeof arr1/sizeof arr1[0]` is `5`. The argument arrays when you call the function also must be the correct size, exactly 5 and 7 respectively. In this context, `&` means pass-by-reference, so the arrays are not copied when you call the function.

You can leverage the template system to generate a function for any size argument array, as well:

```
template< size_t NF, size_t NR >
void fun(Flight (&arr1)[NF], Runway (&arr2)[NR])
```

Such a template may be called with any-sized arrays, and NF and NR will be integral constants set to the proper sizes.

Answer (score 1):

```
ptr1[5].fly();
ptr2[7].run();
```

Comment: The runway class has a member run()? :D

Comment: Armen: Yes, to run away from all the planes that are trying to molest it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Within the function they drop down to pointers so you can use ptr1++ or ++ptr1 and ptr2++ / ++ptr2 to move to the next item in your array.

I am not sure how your function is going to know how many items there are in the arrays as it cannot tell from the code itself so you will require some "terminator" object or to pass the size as an extra parameter.

If you (as is preferable) used std::vector then you can pass a reference or const-reference to your vector into your function and from that you can iterate through the vector instead until you reach the end iterator, and you can also ask for the size of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

use ptr1[i] where i is an offset that increments by sizeof a pointer to the Flight Class. Since arrays are not bounds-checked in C++, your function will have to somehow know the size of the array.  Also, stay away from doing pointer arithmetic like ptr++, you can get into trouble that way.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, the argument list

```
void fun(Flight ptr1[],Runway ptr2[])
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
void fun(Flight* ptr1, Runway* ptr2)
```

You can use the arguments like arrays, as Fred said:

```
ptr1[5].fly();
ptr2[7].run();
```

and you can also use ++ and -- because they are pointers:

```
Flight& FirstFlight = *ptr1;
ptr1++;
Flight& SecondFlight = *ptr1;
Flight& ThirdFlight = ptr1[1];
```

You cannot tell how long the array is unless you pass it as a separate argument.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample program where I have defined the Flight class to demonstrate to access the member of Flight class.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

class Flight {
public:
    int temp;
    int temp1;

    Flight();
    void print();
};

Flight::Flight() {
    temp = 10;  
    temp1 = 11; 
}

void Flight::print() {
    printf("%d %d\n", temp, temp1);
}

void fun(Flight ptr1[]) {
    //ptr1->print();
    ptr1[0].print();
    ptr1[1].print();

    printf("temp=%d\n",ptr1[0].temp);
    printf("sizeof %d \n",sizeof(ptr1));
}

int main() {
    Flight array1[5];

    Flight *p = new Flight;
    //fun(p);
    fun(array1);

    return 0;
}
```

You cannot get the size of array in the fun function, and there is no way to calculate the sizeof array at runtime, so you should add extra parameter in the fun function for getting the sizeof each array.

Yes you can apply the pointer arithmetic to the Flight / Runway array.

The fun(Flight ptr1[]) is equivalent to fun(Flight *ptr1).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use arrays like this, unless there is no other way. Use `std::vector` instead:

```
void fun( const std::vector<Flight> &flights, const std::vector<Runway> &runways)
{
...
...
}
```

And to call the function:

```
std::vector<Flight> flights(5);
std::vector<Runway> runways(2);
fun(array1,array2);
```

Much better this way.